# JsonQueryElasticSearch Processor in Nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

I am working with JsonQueryElasticSearch Processor in Nifi (v1.9.2).

The query string is as below:

```
{
     "query": {
         "bool": {
            "must": [
                { "match":       { "event": "New" }},
                { "match":       { "uniqueId":  "${unique_id}"}},
                { "match":       { "header.schemaVersion": "1.3" }}
            ]
        }
    },
    "sort" : {
        "header.sourceSystemCreationTimestamp" : {"order" : "desc"}
    }
}
```

It's not giving me any result as value of ${unique_id} flow attribute within query is blank. If I hard code the value in query it works as expected. At processor level, I do see the value for ${unique_id} flow attribute.

Thanks much for  your time and help.

Comment: Has flowfile attribute 'unique_id'?

Comment: Yes, verified it again.

Comment: Did you set the query via the query configuration property or are you reading it from the flowfile content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I'm the developer who wrote this processor)

I tried to duplicate the issue by doing the following:

1. Creating an index with several test documents.
2. Using `GenerateFlowFile` -> `JsonQueryElasticsearch`.
3. Putting this simple query in the query parameter of `JsonQueryElasticsearch`:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "from": "${sender}"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "senders": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "from",
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```

All of the expected results were returned. If you are attempting to pass the query in via the flowfile content, you cannot use Expression Language (`${unique_id}`). That's expected behavior because Expression Language is not evaluated on the contents of flowfiles, only on configuration properties.